# WindowsError 32 while trying to os.rename

Tags: python, file, python-2.5

I'm using a base folder `REF_IMAGES` where I keep reference bitmaps for a specified language. I have other several languages folder like `REF_IMAGES-EN`, `REF_IMAGES-NL` etc.

I want to create a script which will rename the base folder to its language ie. `REF_IMAGES-xx` and after rename the selected language folder to the base folder name.

To do this I have a created a txt file which keeps track of the original language in the folder.

My code is the following :

```
import os

# Define paths
baseFolder = 'D:\\IMAGES\\'
imageFolder = 'D:\\IMAGES\\REF_IMAGES'


LanguageFile = 'FolderLanguage.txt'

# Define selected language
language = '-FR'

# Read current language of baseFolder
textFile = open(os.path.join(imageFolder, LanguageFile), "r")
try:
    currentLanguage = textFile.read()
finally:
    textFile.close()

# Rename image folder to original name. This where the error comes up
os.rename(imageFolder, os.path.join(imageFolder, currentLanguage))

# Search for selected language folder and rename it to default one.
for folderName in os.listdir(baseFolder):
    if folderName.endswith(language): # Look for selected language folder
        os.rename(os.path.join(baseFolder, folderName), os.path.join(baseFolder, folderName.split('-')[0])) # Rename selected language folder to base folder
        currentLanguage = language # Save the language the folder is switched to
        textFile = open(os.path.join(imageFolder, LanguageFile), "w")
        try:
            textFile.write("%s" %currentLanguage)
        finally:
            textFile.close()
```

However I get the following error while trying to rename image folder to its original name:

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

I have tried several several Unlocker programs but non of them work. I suppose it is the script blocking it itself but I can't figure out what.

Does anyone know ?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue myself !
The error is in the os.rename syntax. by doing :

```
os.rename(imageFolder, os.path.join(imageFolder, currentLanguage))
```

The output of `os.path.join(imageFolder, currentLanguage)` is `IMAGES\REF_IMAGES\-FR` and not `IMAGES\REF_IMAGES-FR` as I expected

The syntax I use now is:

```
originalName = imageFolder + currentLanguage
os.rename(imageFolder, originalName)
```

Thanks to Mayk who lead me on it actually.

Answer (score 0):

**Test with this:**

> ```
>  try:
>      currentLanguage = textFile.read()
>  except WindowsError:
>    pass
>    textFile.close()
>
>
> try:
>     textFile.write("%s" %currentLanguage)
> except WindowsError:
>    pass
>    textFile.close()
> ```

Comment: Thanks but I forget to add that the error comes up when I try to rename the folder to its original name. I don't have any problems while open and reading the txt file. My bad