# Python Win 32 error while trying to rename a file

Tags: python, windows, rename, csc

I have a folder with several csv-files in it. I have to change the filename of every file with a string that I find in the file. So I tried the script below. It looks like it is working until I try to rename the file.

What did I try:

1. First I didn't have the file.close() line in the program, but did didn't fix the problem
2. I added a line print(file.closed) to see if the file was actually closed
3. I tried to get the os.rename out of the indented 'with' block. But I keep getting the same error
4. I tried to get the os.rename out of any block. But then I get a Winerror 123, where it sais that the filename , directoryname etc. is incorrect.
5. I also read the questions [WindowsError 32 while trying to os.rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685152/windowserror-32-while-trying-to-os-rename) and [Windows Error: 32 when trying to rename file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456243/windows-error-32-when-trying-to-rename-file-in-python).
6. I understood that maybe I had to close the file with f.close since this is the handler, but that didn't work as well.

The code that I tried:

```
for f in glob.glob("/path/*.csv"):
    with open(f, "r") as file:
        #read the lines in the csv-file
        data = file.read()
        #search the lines that have been read for a pattern and save that in "search"
        search = re.findall("some_pattern", data)
        #The result was a list. With this line I tried to change it into a string
        file.close()
        Listtostring = ''.join([str(elem) for elem in search])
        #I only want to use a part of the match in the new file name
        name = Listtostring.replace("part_of_string", "")
        os.rename(f,f+name)
```

I hope somebody can give me some tips and explain what I am doing wrong. Pretty new to Python, so if you can give me some insight in my mistakes, than it's appreciated!

Comment: If you get an [ERROR_INVALID_NAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) it stands to reason that your are passing an invalid path name. It is beyond me why anyone would think that closing a file handle would address that error.

Comment: I don't get why os.rename(f, f+name) is working on my mac but not on a windows computer. Could this be an issue?

Comment: Not knowing why your code works *is* indeed an issue.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and time. It seemed that one of the files that was opened was still busy in some process and therefore the code didn’t work. I first closed all the applications that were running, but that didn’t work. After that I restarted the computer and the script worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments and time. It seemed that one of the files that was opened was still busy in some process and therefore the code didn’t work. I first closed all the applications that were running, but that didn’t work. After that I restarted the computer and the script worked fine!